# Windows Azure Authentication not working after publish my asp.net web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure

I have an asp.net website using Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication,

AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(assetSvcResourceId, clientId, redirectURI, PromptBehavior.Auto, new UserIdentifier(lastUser, UserIdentifierType.OptionalDisplayableId), "nux=1");

The code works fine on local machine, it pops up a window to ask me to sign in, but after publishing to windows azure, the pop up disappears, and directly access my website page.

Update:I use remote debug to debug the azure website, found that this code will throw execption:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, UserIdentifier userId, String extraQueryParameters)

Exception:Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Error code:-2147467259

I'm look at this, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Update: I have realized AAD using another method.
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory

Comment: Any updates on this? I am facing the same issue.